# How Can i get fc-token from arkose lab in Twitter verification

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter, captcha

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd4ac.png)

I am trying to use Selenium in Python to retrieve a specific HTML element, more specifically its value.

```
`<input type="hidden" id="FunCaptcha-Token" name="fc-token" value="702178f80cd6ade39.2875608305|r=eu-west-1|meta=3|meta_width=558|meta_height=523|metabgclr=transparent|metaiconclr=%23555555|guitextcolor=%23000000|pk=2CB16598-CB82-4CF7-B332-5990DB66F3AB|at=40|ag=101|cdn_url=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc|lurl=https%3A%2F%2Faudio-eu-west-1.arkoselabs.com|surl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com|smurl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc%2Fassets%2Fstyle-manager">`
```

How can I retrieve it with Selenium?

I am using the following code:

```
 token_element =  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "fc-token"))
            )
            logger.info(f"Token key{token_element}")
            publickey = re.search(r'pk=([0-9A-Fa-f-]+)', token_element.get_attribute("value"))
            logger.info(f"PUBLIC key{publickey}")
```

But it's never found. I added a print statement to check the DOM:

`print(f"DOM\n {self.driver.page_source}")`

But the element is missing.

Can someone help me resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)